# Evaluating the limit $\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{x-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

How would you solve $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}-1}{x-1}\right)$
?

I tried multiplying it by the conjugate. I don't know how to get rid of the square root.

Comment: I tried multiplying it by the conjugate. I don't know how to get rid of the square root.

Comment: You can't, it is out of the domain.

Comment: Are you sure that's $x \rightarrow -1$ and not $x \rightarrow 1^{-}$?

Comment: Yup, this is the question. I'm sure.

Comment: If it is indeed $x\to-1$, you will necessarily have square roots of negative numbers somewhere. The expression has to be defined near the point $x=-1$ for the limit to make sense.

Comment: Unless your course deals with complex numbers, $x\to-1$ is a typo for $x\to 1$. Assuming that it's a typo, you can use Autolatry' s hint.

Comment: I hope it's a typo. Otherwise, it's going to be a complex number right? That's the only solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge hint:

\begin{equation}
(\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}+1) = x-1
\end{equation}

Comment: But then it's gonna be 1/(x√+1). When you substitute x for -1, it's undefined